# Opening string as image in python/pygame

Tags: python, string, image, file-upload, pygame

I've saved an image as string:

```
import base64, os

with open(os.path.join("sprites","asteroids.png"), "rb") as imageFile:
    str_file = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

with open(os.path.join("sprites","asteroids_string.s "), "wb") as stringFile:
    stringFile.write(str_file)
```

I want to open the string in a different project and load it as an image. I've tried two approaches:

Simply `self.image = pygame.image.fromstring(os.path.join("sprites", "asteroids_string.s "), GRID, "RGB")` and then I get `TypeError: must be bytes, not str`

```
with open(os.path.join("sprites","asteroids_string.s "), "rb") as stringFile:
       self.asteroid_string = stringFile.read()
self.image = pygame.image.fromstring(self.asteroid_string, GRID, "RGB")
```

and then I get `ValueError: String length does not equal format and resolution size`

Where's my mistake?

Comment: use `pygame.image.tostring` to create correct string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save `PNG` as a string. `PNG` means compressed image with headers.

`fromstring` expects string with uncompressed image without headers.

Probably only `pygame.image.tostring` can create correct string for `fromstring`